# Try Catch in main or in method

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

So I am task with getting input for clock time. With 3 method 
gethour , getmin , getsec inside the method we are suppose to check if the value is between 0 and 60 if its not throw exception.
My question is : 
Is it better to do try catch inside my main or should i do it inside the method?

I did it in method cause i felt that it was better(just my thought) and my prof deducted marks from it stating its better to do it in main. So i just want to know which is actually better and why.

Comment: Why don't you ask your professor? He is deciding what is good and what is bad in this case.

Comment: It is often more appropriate for a method to throw an exception than to hide the fact that an error occurred. If you were told that your method should _throw_ an exception, then it should throw it.

Comment: @talex the problem is he recommended someone else that did their try catch in the main to do it in their methods.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you're catching exceptions you should catch at whichever level is the most reasonable to handle that error.

If you can't handle it, you should let it propagate up the stack. If you can handle it in a reasonable way then you should catch it and take the appropriate action to correct the failure.

That's really all there is to it. Whenever you write a catch statement you should be asking yourself "is there actually anything I can do to fix this at this point in the code?"

For example, if you expect to find a configuration file and it's missing then maybe the appropriate action is to fall back to some sensible default configuration values.

Without your code or any context of what the error is, or what levels of your call stack are doing what, we can't tell you any more than that.

Answer (score 1):

If your method **should** throw exception by definition than it doesn't need to catch any exception, because it should be defined as throwing the exception and actually throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

The practice in exception handling is that you should be catching exceptions closets to where they occur. It makes it easier to trace back, while also makes better flow control. Try-catch is mainly used to prevent your program from crashing upon very unusual circumstances, while displaying user-friendly error message to user and logging the complete error somewhere else.

However, if you are already handling the exceptions correctly, in a task-specific way, then a more general try-catch method can be used as a failsafe for bugs in edge cases that didn't get caught during testing, or for very rare occurences.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to handle exceptions only when you can take some meaningful action on it. I don't have your full example, but I suppose that if you catch the exception inside the method, you would need to return some value to the caller. And then how would the caller know if you had invalid data (outside of 0..60 range) in your method? 
On the other hand if you throw an exception and handle it in the main(), you would have more options to do that and the method would not hide the error situation.
This is also called separation of concerns. Method functionality and error handling are separate concerns and they should not be mixed. If you handle the exception in main(), you'll have a better SoC: functionality in the method, error handling in main()

Answer (score 0):

Actually it doesn’t matter where to put the try-catch block. If you don’t want to catch the exception inside your method and throwing back to caller method i.e main() , then you can handle it there. It purely depends on the requirements. I am not sure why your professor did this. You can ask him.